# Convert increment value

Tags: c#

I tried to convert incremented value to string.

```
i++.ToString()
```

The above statement working fine.

```
++i.ToString()
```

This one showing error line. Why?

Comment: Although this is trivial for someone to reproduce, I would encourage you to include the exact error details you encounter in future questions. Simply saying "this one showing error" makes things unclear.

Comment: It is showing error lines in red...

Comment: Here you can see that the operator precendence is different for `i++` and `++i`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx The second belongs to the "Unary" group but the `.` belongs to "Primary". So `.ToString` is executed first.

Comment: Presumably there's an error *message* - which you should *always* include in the question, when you mention an error. (It's like saying "It throws an exception" without telling us the exception.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in the second expression the `ToString()` method of `i` is called first and the `++` operator is meaningless for strings. On the other hand, in your first expression, the integer `i` is get incremented by one and the method `ToString()` is called. So you get the string representation of your number. You could conver it, as already ulugbek-umirov pointed out in his comment:

```
(++i).ToString();
```

Please have a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G5sY42).

Comment: Then how to convert it?

Comment: @Jesuraja use `(++i).ToString()`.

Comment: do you mean _meaningless_ ?

Answer (score 2):

Because the second means:

```
++(i.ToString())  // Oops, compiler error
```

and string type can not be incremented.

Comment: Remove the additional `)`

Comment: @Jesuraja Removed. Thanks, it was typo.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by the different operator precendence of `i++` and `++i`.

`i++` belongs to "Primary" whereas `++i` belongs to the "Unary" group. But since the `.` belongs also to "Primary" is has a higher precendence . So `.ToString` is executed first. You cannot use `++` operator on a string.

You can wrap it in paranthesis:

```
(++i).ToString()
```

Reference: [Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`(++i).ToString()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have to options

make it in 2 times:

```
  i++;
  i.ToString();
```

Use parenthesis to set priority (first increase then convert to string)

```
(++i).ToString();
```

or

```
(i++).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the precedence of the operators being applied.
In your instruction you're trying to apply an int-increment to a string.
If you want to post increment you should do:

```
(++i).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers and comments saying that this is due to anything "executing first" are misleading. This problem is due to the higher *precedence* of `.` relative to `++`(prefix). Order of evaluation has nothing to do with it really - especially since `++i.ToString()` *does not compile* and therefore there is no evaluation at all (hence no order in which it happens).

See also [precedence vs associativity vs order](http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/).

Answer (score 1):

Because when ++ is used as a postfix, it will increase its value immediately then covert it to string using ToString();

Instead if you use ++ as prefix operator then it will convert the existing value to string using ToString() then it will try to increment the value, so in this case you are getting error on increment a string value...

so try using parenthesis for increasing its precedence as (++i).ToString();

Comment: Appreciation for your first answer :)